Hidden operation
Here are ten non-negative integers represented by symbols in numerical order. They're the ten first of their kind.
What are the symbols telling you?
           ◑ ◑ ◑ ◐ ◑ ◐ ◐ ◐ ◑ ◑


 Answer: +2 +5 +2 -2 -6 +6 -5 -13 -6 -13 

Hint 1:

 English

Hint 2:

 Start with 0 and use 'Hint 1'.


One thing I noticed is that rot13(gur nofbyhgr inyhr bs rnpu inyhr qbrf abg rkprrq guvegrra, juvpu yrnqf zr gb oryvrir vg'f fbzr fbeg bs fhofgvghgvba pvcure. Vs guvegrra vf nqqrq gb rirel inyhr naq qrpbqrq nf N1M26, V tbg "cfcyugvnun".) Not sure if I'm on the right track though.

@BlueHerring I see, while it's true that the last row will yield letters, it's not via the method you suggested. Figuring out what numbers the symbols represent is the crucial part (taking help from the hints)
